# jQuery finding select elements by value

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, html-select

In jQuery, why does `$("#myid").val()` return the value of a select element but `$("select[value='abcd']")` does not find a select element that has a value of abcd? And how do I do the latter - find all select elements in a form that have a value of 'abcd'?

EDIT: I managed to retrieve the select element ids with a workaround: I added the select's id as an attribute on all its' options. Then I used: $("option[value=abcd]:selected") to find all selected options with the value of abcd and finally $(this).attr("myAttr") inside .each(function(){  }) to get the id.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is no `value` attribute for the `select` tag so it doesn't get selected. You can use jQuery [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) pseudo-class selector or [`has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) method to get select tag which contains option tag with certain attribute value.

```
$("select:has([value='abcd'])") 
// or 
$("select").has("[value='abcd'])")
// or
$("select [value='abcd']").parent()
```

---

**UPDATE :** If you want to select all select tag with selected value is `abcd` then use [`filter()`](https://api.jquery.com/filter/) method.

```
$("select").filter(function(){
   return this.value == 'abcd';
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately none of those solutions worked for me, so I'll keep using my custom attribute. Thanks

Comment: @lindAt : what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I already have the value, and now I want to find the id of the select element(s) that have that value

Comment: @lindAt :  try `$("select:has([value='abcd'])") .attr('id')`

Comment: @lindAt: id of `select` or `option` ?

Comment: I need the id of the select

Comment: @lindAt :  try `$("select:has([value='abcd'])").map(function(){ return this.id; }).get()`

Answer (score 0):

you can use following method to get selected value

> $("#id option:selected").val();

Comment: This is the wrong way around - I already have the value, and now I want the id of the select element that has the value.

Comment: var id = $("#mySelect").children(":selected").attr("id");